# Using Intersect and Join to analyze data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, attribute-joins, intersect

I am attempting to calculate area covered by roads within a grid. I have used the intersect(analysis) tool to create a new shp file that segmented the road features according to the grid. I then joined the roads (along with their calculated segment lengths) with the grid cell to sum the total road length within each grid cell. This all works except that the join tool is including road segments that are in adjacent grid cells.

These segments touch the edges of the cell boundaries and are essentially being included in the road segment length sums for 2 grid cells. Is there a way to fix this issue without having to individually move each segment so it doesn't touch adjacent grid cells?

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 for Desktop. These shapefiles are simple, local and created by my previous project coordinator using Arc.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the advanced license:

The Tabulate intersection tool should allow you to get the values that you are looking for without the first step even. (assuming you mean a shapefile grid(or fishnet).

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/tabulate-intersection.htm

This tool should give you the total length within each grid. Easy day.

NOTE: If not, I would suggest using HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN with a spatial join(assuming you are using a spatial join) to assign them to the correct grid.